# How to display Icon in middle of screen in react native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

Here, I am displaying `"icon="check-decagram" type="MaterialCommunityIcons"` in center, but its just coming in center and 20 padding from top. I have to display it middle of the mobile screen. I tried may be I am doing some wrong .Please correct me .

```
return(
       <ImageBackground source={BG} style={styles.imgBG}>
           <ScrollView>
             <View>
                <Header title={title} icon={icon} navigation={navigation} />
             </View>
             <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', backgroundColor: '#ffff',}}>
             <View style={{
                       flexDirection:'column', backgroundColor:'#fff',alignItems:'center',paddingTop:20,justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <IconXL icon="check-decagram" type="MaterialCommunityIcons" style={{ color: 'green' }}/>

             </View>
             <View style={{
                       flexDirection:'row', backgroundColor:'#ffff',padding:20,flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
                <SmallText textColor="grey" text={`v${updateResponse.updateStatusList.currentAppVersion} `}/>
                <SmallText textColor="grey" text={`${updateResponse.updateStatusList.desc}`}/>
             </View>
             </View>

          </ScrollView>

      </ImageBackground>

 )}
```

// Thanks

Comment: Try adding to wrapper view style display: "flex" and some height value.

Comment: I can add height or padding but that would be like hard code , is there anything that  display icon in center ? Any props ?

Comment: `justifyContent `and `alignItems `are only work if `display: "flex"` is selected. But ıf you dont give a height value the wrapper view will have the lowest height possible so aligning vertically won't work. If you want to display your icon middle of the screen instead of the view you can use `position: "absolute" `and `Dimensions` component to center your Icon.

Comment: hi, try to add one more property in superview of icon

Answer (score 2):

try to add two more property `height: '100%'` and `width: '100%'` in superview of icon,

like,

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'column',height: '100%',width: '100%',backgroundColor:'#fff',alignItems:'center',paddingTop:2,justifyContent: 'center'}}>
  <IconXL icon="check-decagram" type="MaterialCommunityIcons" style={{ color:'green' }}/>
</View>
```

Hope this works for you,

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like.

```
<View style={{
flex: 1, 
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center', 
backgroundColor: 'blue'
}}>
<Text style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
    Your Text
</Text>
```